# Where to find expiring data for Playstation Plus on the PS4

Tags: psn, ps4, playstation-plus

I was looking around for an equivalent to PS3s account management but it seems not to exist or is it hidden? I would appreciate some help on the matter since I need to know when my Playstation Plus expires.

Or am I able to check this on https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in the settings menu, with your other Account information (I forget if this is it's own top level thing of if it's under Play Station Network) there's a "Services" section. Inside Services you'll see Playstation Plus and you can see the begining/end of your service date and your auto-renew setting.

Comment: I can't seem to find PS+ expiration on the SEN site. But there is a way to check it on PS3, 4 and Vita for sure.

Comment: Yeah, Found it on PS4: Settings -> PSN -> Account Information -> Service List -> Playstation Plus

Comment: Ah! I wasn't sure of the exact path since Im' at work. When I'm hope I'll try and grab a relevant screenshot too.

Answer (score 31):

Easiest way is to go to the Sony PSN website and look under Media (hopefully you've downloaded a few of the Instant Game Collection).  You'll see the expiration date which correlates to your PS+ expiry date.

Comment: I can't find this "Media" thing. Can you give more information?

Comment: Found it. https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/liquid/cam/media/media-list.action

Answer (score 3):

Log into SonyEntertainmentNetwork.com and then go to this address:

https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/cam/media/media-list.action

You'll see all your purchased games along with the free PSN games. The latter ones will all have the same expiration date.

That date is your Playstation Plus expiration date.

Disclaimer: This answer is correct as of this writing but might become incorrect if Sony changes their website.

Comment: At least on mobile, that link doesn't show expiration dates for your Plus free games. (As of today...)

Comment: I just checked and in a desktop computer the expiration dates are still shown. It seems Sony follows the lame fashion of creating crippled websites for mobile just for being mobile, when in reality a good website should show exactly the SAME info in both versions (computer and mobile), only with different design. Maybe try the browser option of "show like in a computer" if you don't have a desktop computer at hand.

Answer (score 2):

For PS4, go to Settings > PSN > Account Information > Services List > Playstation Plus. Once you are in, it will show you your sign up date, your expiration and automatic renewal date. You can also deactivate the auto-renewal feature.

Answer (score -1):

for PS3 you go to account management then service list there you will see your PS plus account start and end date

Comment: The OP already knows about the PS3 system, this was about PS4.